# JSON Where clause filter using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Tags: json, linq

I have a json string which looks something like this (simplified version):

```
{"Statistics":[
                {"Direction":"2-WAY","AADT":8129,"BC":254},
                {"Direction":"NEG","AADT":3956,"BC":124},
                {"Direction":"POS","AADT":4173,"BC":128}
            ]
}
```

I also have a c# program started:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
namespace TrafficCounterJSON {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            string jsonString = "{\"Statistics\":[{\"Direction\":\"2-WAY\",\"AADT\":8129},{\"Direction\":\"NEG\",\"AADT\":3956}]}";
            var jObjectt = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(jsonString);
        }//main

   }
}
```

I would like to know how I could run a know how to use Newtonsoft.Json.Linq to query the items in the json string as follows:

I want all the statistics rows where "Direction = NEG"

I cannot seem to figure out the correct syntax to get those results (via a select ... where clause)

So based on input below, I finally just built a model for the json data (I used this site: http://json2csharp.com)

Below is a fuller version of the json:

```
 {  "RequestId":"068f38ed-532c-442c-aae7-748112926b0d",

    "Parameters":{"AgencyId":25,"LocalId":"710541"},

    "Statistics":[
        {"LastCollectionDate":"\/Date(1479272400000-0500)\/","Direction":"2-WAY","AADT":8129,"BC":254,"TimePeriod":"AM","PeakHour":"07:00 - 08:00","PeakHourVolume":832,"CommercialPeakHourVolume":24},
        {"LastCollectionDate":"\/Date(1479272400000-0500)\/","Direction":"2-WAY","AADT":8129,"BC":254,"TimePeriod":"PM","PeakHour":"16:00 - 17:00","PeakHourVolume":863,"CommercialPeakHourVolume":16},
        {"LastCollectionDate":"\/Date(1479272400000-0500)\/","Direction":"NEG","AADT":3956,"BC":124,"TimePeriod":"AM","PeakHour":"07:00 - 08:00","PeakHourVolume":234,"CommercialPeakHourVolume":9},
        {"LastCollectionDate":"\/Date(1479272400000-0500)\/","Direction":"NEG","AADT":3956,"BC":124,"TimePeriod":"PM","PeakHour":"16:00 - 17:00","PeakHourVolume":525,"CommercialPeakHourVolume":7},
        {"LastCollectionDate":"\/Date(1479272400000-0500)\/","Direction":"POS","AADT":4173,"BC":128,"TimePeriod":"AM","PeakHour":"07:00 - 08:00","PeakHourVolume":598,"CommercialPeakHourVolume":15},
        {"LastCollectionDate":"\/Date(1479272400000-0500)\/","Direction":"POS","AADT":4173,"BC":128,"TimePeriod":"PM","PeakHour":"16:00 - 17:00","PeakHourVolume":338,"CommercialPeakHourVolume":9}
    ],
    "AadtHistory":[
        {"Year":2017,"Aadt":8202,"Source":"Grown from 2016"},
        {"Year":2016,"Aadt":8129,"Source":null},
        {"Year":2015,"Aadt":6194,"Source":"Grown from 2014"},
        {"Year":2014,"Aadt":6061,"Source":null},
        {"Year":2013,"Aadt":5538,"Source":"Grown from 2012"},
        {"Year":2012,"Aadt":5617,"Source":"Grown from 2011"},
        {"Year":2011,"Aadt":5623,"Source":null},
        {"Year":2000,"Aadt":6090,"Source":"Flowmap"},
        {"Year":1997,"Aadt":5210,"Source":"Flowmap"},
        {"Year":1992,"Aadt":5360,"Source":"Flowmap"},
        {"Year":1988,"Aadt":4330,"Source":"Flowmap"}]
    }
```

Here is the corresponding model I am now using:

```
public class Parameters {
    public int AgencyId { get; set; }
    public string LocalId { get; set; }
}

public class Statistic {
    public DateTime LastCollectionDate { get; set; }
    public string Direction { get; set; }
    public int AADT { get; set; }
    public int BC { get; set; }
    public string TimePeriod { get; set; }
    public string PeakHour { get; set; }
    public int PeakHourVolume { get; set; }
    public int CommercialPeakHourVolume { get; set; }
}

public class AadtHistory {
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Aadt { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject {
    public string RequestId { get; set; }
    public Parameters Parameters { get; set; }
    public List<Statistic> Statistics { get; set; }
    public List<AadtHistory> AadtHistory { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a small sample of the code I am using the pull data from rows in the Statistics array (from the json string)

```
var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonResponseString);
     foreach (Statistic stat in myObject.Statistics) {
       Console.WriteLine("AADT:" + stat.AADT);                        
}
```

Comment: You should create a C# class to model your JSON object. Let's say the class is named `JsonModel`. You then do `JsonModel myJsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonModel>(jsonString);`

Comment: I found this link: http://json2csharp.com/ so I used that to create the model.  I will go that route.  I was originally thinking of doing a dynamic data pull such as direction = (string)jsonObj["Statistics"][3]["Direction"];   But I will use the more formal model approach, and I will update my post with working code.  thank you Sam.

Comment: Now that you've created your model, do you still have a question? Perhaps the part of your question that you just added should actually be an answer that you can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there after adding the model. You could now use Linq to filter based on direction.

```
 var filteredList = myObject.Statistics.Where(x=>x.Direction == "NEG");
```